# Examples of 2 factor authentication?

Tags: authentication, hipaa

I am doing a HIPAA application soon and it requires 2 factor authentication. Can anyone give me an example? I am thinking a secure login and then a form that requires the user to enter their birth date or something.

Thanks,
Darren

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia has a great listing of various types of Two Factor Auth.  Check it out [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-factor_authentication#Types_of_Two-factor_Authentication).

Answer (score 8):

There are 3 general types of factors:

1. “Something you know” – memorized information (e.g., a password or answer to a
   secret question).
2. “Something you have” – possession of a unique item containing secret
   information (e.g., a smart card, bar code, or USB-interface device).
3. “Something you are” – a physical trait that can be converted to digital
   information using specialized hardware (e.g., a retina or fingerprint scan or voice
   recording analysis).

You need to pick from 2 of these 3 categories to have true 2-factor authentication.

Answer (score 2):

2-factor authentication usually requires something the user *knows*, like a password, and a token from something the user *has*, like a SecurID fob, or nowadays maybe a biometric identifier, like a fingerprint reader.

A password & birthday, while being two distinct things, are both *knows* items and wouldn't constitute a proper 2-factor identification.

See [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-factor_authentication/) or search for information using "2 factor authentication",  Google and Bing both show lots of references.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing (password + verification input) is still single factor authentication.

Two factor authentication also requires something the user has in their possession (smart card, dongle, etc.)

Three factor authentication (for completeness) is all of the above plus some sort of biometric input from the user (fingerprint, retinal scan, hand geometry)

Answer (score 0):

2FA will be simple One time password as hardware or software (mobile , PC ) and

we have done few deployments of 2FA tokens for HIPAA compliance.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. Is it true the 2FA is for the server access and not the application access?

Answer (score 0):

CryptoPhoto is a very easy to use "Strong Authentication" 2FA solution, with additional protection aginst Phising and other threats.  You don't have to ship expensive hardware gadgetry to end users either - it's a fully self-contained solution.